# Dynamically create least number of nxn subplots from number

Tags: python, plot

Let's say that I have X number of subplots that I would like to make. If I wanted to create the *least* number of subplots (with the larger number being the rows), we would have:

```
1 = 1x1
2 = 2x1
3 = 2x2
4 = 2x2
5 = 3x2
6 = 3x2
7 = 3x3
8 = 3x3
9 = 3x3
10 = 4x3
11 = 4x3
12 = 4x3
```

However, this is cumbersome to code without a dynamic sort of approach.  Might there be a function I am missing that can do this in a more automated fashion?